# iPhone project to iPad project in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm wondering if it's possible to make the iPhone app project I have into an iPad project? So I won't have to redo all coding and connecting everything again. I've gotten that far that I can make the iPhone project run on the iPad but then it's only in the iPhone's size.

I hope this makes sense!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to recreate all those views as iPad views instead of iPhone views.  Both would be included into the universal app in a single distribution binary.  At runtime, load them dynamically based on the platform.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     // The device is an iPad running iOS 3.2 or later. load the appropriate Xibs
}
else {
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch. load the appropriate Xibs
}
```

See [Creating a Universal Application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24)

You may be able to design some views to dynamically stretch / resize and won't have to touch them much, however I suggest you tailor the tablet experience more than just "upsized", otherwise you aren't doing the device justice.